# Why not showing custom module in odoo

Tags: odoo

I have developed new module but facing problem.

Installing custom module on server, without access rights on menus and views, my module works properly.
But when i install module with access rights , just blank page appear instead of list of installed module.

Actual screen:
  [image: Actual screen]

Blank screen:
  [image: Blank screen]

Access right:
  [image: Access right]

Security:
  [image: Security]

Comment: put your acces rights and screen picture of the blank page

Comment: This problem i am facing on remote server whereas its working fine on my local configured system with odoo 10.

Comment: no you make it a code the photo are not shown edit you question again

Comment: Would you please tell me what possible causes for module accessing problems on server?

Comment: Are you sure the model_id for students_student_registration_access_right_user is correct in your excel file???

Comment: did you add `groups="your_group"` to your menu tag?

Comment: groups="students.group_user"    as per i described in csv file

Answer (score 1):

One of the thing that i learned when i was learning security in odoo:

if you are getting a blank page that's mean that you did not give you user the needed groups is  `base.group_user`  Witch is employee group. because backend is for employee of the company you need to give the user this group in order to see the backend. here is a picture of my screen when i logged ing using the administrator but i removed manually the `base.group_user` :

[image: Blank page with administrator account]

so if you are  creating  a new groups for your new user you need to give it at least base.roup_user

in code example stock_security model :

```xml
<record id="group_stock_user" model="res.groups">
        <field name="name">User</field>
        <field name="category_id" ref="base.module_category_warehouse_management"/>
        <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('base.group_user')), (4, ref('stock.group_locations'))]"/>
      </record>
```

Here they are defining a new group Named user that include `base.group_user`

so my question is are you connecting with administrator or a new user

now i have two question :

are you connecting using Administrator or a new user with new groups?

if you are using administrator is the screen i blank page like the one in the picture or you have the menu apps and setting but you don't have your costum menus?

EDITS :

if the menu is not shown to user then the user don't have acces 
 rights to the model you need to gave the read acces to the group

```
ir.model.access.csv

 "id","name","model_id:id","group_id:id","perm_read","perm_write","perm_create","perm_unlink"
 // in this example all user can read record of model : model.name because you didn't specify the group
 "unic_xml_id_for_every_record","name what ever you want","model_model_name",,1,0,0,0

 // in this example only user belong to group some_group_xmlid can read record of model.name
 "unic_xml_id_for_every_record","name what ever you want","model_model_name","some_group_xmlid",1,0,0,0

 // user belong to group some_group_xmlid can read and create records of model.name
 "unic_xml_id_for_every_record","name what ever you want","model_model_name","some_group_xmlid",1,0,1,0
```

exmple

```
ir.model.access.csv

 "id","name","model_id:id","group_id:id","perm_read","perm_write","perm_create","perm_unlink"
 "mode_name_id_1","model_name all","model_model_name",,1,0,0,0
 "mode_name_id_2","model_name create_acces","model_model_name","some_group_xmlid",1,0,1,0
```

Comment: With administrator and user, its working properly on my locally configured server but its not working on remote server e.g www.myodoo.com.pk like on 'digital ocean'

Comment: so every thing works fine but in remote server nothing is shown i really don't know you should see the Js console to see what are the errors

Comment: can you tell me , what possible causes for this reason while programing in security/security.xml file and views?

Comment: if you remove the security xml file everything will show in remote server

Comment: yes if i do remove / disable security.xml file in __manifest__.py file
and remove groups setting in view then , everything is working fine.

Comment: if you connect using administrator account what is showing in the screen

Comment: Its work fine if i logged in as administrator , no message or error show..
without security and access rights

Comment: how are you creating your new user by UI  or by code and how are giving it's groups

Comment: when you log with new user do you get the same problem as i explained in my answer blank page without iven the menu bar

Comment: here are images :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TC9K.png

  https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBgtQ.png

  https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjzkL.png

  https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghQtC.png

Comment: did you add `r.model.access.csv` to you `__manifest__.py` because if your user don't have acces rigths on the model to read record the menu will be shown

Comment: check my edits to see if you give your user the read acces because even you give the menu the right group but your user don't have acces to read record the menu will not be shown to the user

Comment: I have given read access to user.  Secondly i have ir.model.access.csv included in __manifest__.py file. Also running module properly on my server which is configured  in virtual machine. BUt its not working properly on live server.

Comment: so you saying that everything you want is good locally and when you run in live server you have this error did you try a new database from scrutch

Comment: Exactly ! this issue.  No i didn't try new database on live server.

Comment: try it may be you are doing something wrong with upgrading

Comment: What exactly causes for that issue even on local configured which is now i am facing and on live server.

Comment: Cherif Odoo ! i wonder running code on odoo 10 is not working now.
same issue as i mentioned above or talking about is happening with me current code on locally configured server in virtual machine is happing?

Answer (score 0):

Could you just show our what you JS console showing?

Answer (score 0):

if you want your user to see a menu that show view of `model.test` and let us suppose that your used_id is `test_user`
 and your group xml `group_xml_id`:

1. add the group to your user :

```xml
        <!-- 
             this will add the group to the existing groups if you want 
             to replace them [(6,0,[ref('group_xml_id'),]]
         -->
         <record id="test_user" model="res.users">
            ...
            ...
            <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('group_xml_id')]"/>
        </record>
```

2. add access role to users of  `group_xml_id`:

   `"user_test_full_acces","USER TEST FULL ACCES","model_model_test","group_xml_id",1,1,1,1`
3. if you want the menu to be seen only by the user belong to group `group_xml_id`:

```xml
<menu .......  groups="module_name.group_xml_id"/>
```

thouse are the roles that you need to respect in order to see the menu.

this query will show if your user have the wanted groups if you don't find the group 
then you are doing something wrong you should check `__manifest__` may be you forget to 
put the xml file.

```sql
select p.name, g.name from res_users u
                               INNER JOIN res_partner p on u.partner_id = p.id 
                   inner join res_groups_users_rel r on u.id = r.uid
                   INNER JOIN res_groups g on r.gid = g.id
order by p.name
```